# Stop matplotlib 3D surface plot from having axis labels cut off

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am writing a piece of code that models the interaction of an atom in electric and magnetic fields.  Part of this requires me to produce 3D plots of the interaction potentials at a given height.  The full code to produce these plots is very long and split across several modules however the relevant plotting part is:

```
# Function to plot 'PlotValues' at a height 'z'
def Plot_AtHeight(self, PlotValues, z=500, ReturnFig=False, ShowTime=False):

    # Calls out to the relevant function to calculate the values and return
    # these as an array
    PlotArray = self.Get_AtHeight(PlotValues, z)

    pylab.rcParams.update( \
        {'axes.labelsize': 18,
         'text.fontsize': 18,
         'xtick.labelsize': 18,
         'ytick.labelsize': 18
         })

    fig = pylab.figure()
    ax = Axes3D(fig)

    # Make the arrays of the points at which the values are calculated
    X, Y = np.mgrid[Xmin:Xmax:complex(0,Xpoints),
                   Ymin:Ymax:complex(0,Ypoints)]

    ax.plot_surface(X, Y, PlotArray, cmap=cm.jet)

    ax.set_xlabel('Position, x (nm)')
    ax.set_ylabel('Position, y (nm)')

    if PlotValues   == 'B':           ax.set_zlabel('Field Strength (G)',         fontsize=18)
    elif PlotValues == 'E':           ax.set_zlabel('Field Strength (V/m)',       fontsize=18)
    elif PlotValues == 'U_Stark':     ax.set_zlabel('Stark Interaction (J)',      fontsize=18)
    elif PlotValues == 'U_Zeeman':    ax.set_zlabel('Zeeman Interaction (J)',     fontsize=18)
    elif PlotValues == 'U':           ax.set_zlabel('Interaction Potential (J)',  fontsize=18)
    elif PlotValues == 'U_Stark_mK':  ax.set_zlabel('Stark Interaction (mK)',     fontsize=18)
    elif PlotValues == 'U_Zeeman_mK': ax.set_zlabel('Zeeman Interaction (mK)',    fontsize=18)
    elif PlotValues == 'U_mK':        ax.set_zlabel('Interaction Potential (mK)', fontsize=18)

    # If we are not in a time averaged environment then display the current
    # time (in ns) as the title to 1 decimal place.
    if not self.TimeAveraged and ShowTime:
        TimeStr = str(time*10**9)
        try:
            TimeTo1dp = '.'.join([TimeStr.split('.')[0], TimeStr.split('.')[1][0]])
        except:
            TimeTo1dp = TimeStr
        ax.set_title("t = %sns" % TimeTo1dp, fontsize=18)

    if not ReturnFig: pylab.show()
    elif ReturnFig: return fig
```

An example of the plots this returns is:

[image: one of the plots created]

You can see that the axis labels and ticks are a bit messy.  Particularly, I was hoping someone might know how to stop the image being cut off at the bottom (i.e. so that all of the 1000 is clear).  I have this problem at a lot of angles, sometime the axis label is cut off, sometimes the ticks but essentially the window python opens to view and save the plot does not seem big enough, and expanding it scales the whole image so the labels/ticks are still cut off.

Any help would be appreciated and please don't mention reducing fontsize or removing the labels as this is going into a report and so these are fixed.

Thanks.

Answer (score 27):

You can set a viewing "distance" to your plot by, for example,

> ax.dist = 13

Comment: The default value is 10.

Comment: This worked when combined with `fig.gca(projection="3d")` rather than `ax = Axes3D(fig)`

Comment: after `dist` attribute was deprecated, the following can be used `ax.set_box_aspect(aspect=None, zoom=0.8)`