# Z label gets cut off matplotlib 3D plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook

Here is my MWE:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

plt.rcParams.update({'font.size': 12})
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(8, 6), layout='constrained')

ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')

# Data
zline = np.random.randint(0, 10, 50)
xline = np.random.randint(0, 10, 50)
yline = np.random.randint(0, 10, 50)

ax.scatter(xline, yline, zline, 'gray', s=10)
ax.set_xlabel('X Label')
ax.set_ylabel('Y Label')
ax.set_zlabel('Z Label')
# ax.set_box_aspect(None, zoom=0.9)
ax.view_init(30, -135, 0) 

plt.show()

fig.savefig("test-figure.png", dpi=150, bbox_inches='tight')
```

There is a answer here: [Labels are cut off](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62591523/labels-are-cut-off) but it is not working for me. The z label is still cut off.

[image]

I try another methods: [Stop matplotlib 3D surface plot from having axis labels cut off](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14748345/stop-matplotlib-3d-surface-plot-from-having-axis-labels-cut-off) and [matplotlib 3D plot Z label cut off](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77577613/matplotlib-3d-plot-z-label-cut-off) by adding `ax.set_box_aspect(None, zoom=0.85)`. But it also adds extra space at the right, top, and bottom of the figure.

[image]

May I ask if there are any methods to save the figure using a tight layout without adding any spaces and preserving the z label?

Edit: The installed Python version is 3.11.8, and the Matplotlib version is 3.8.3.

Comment: Have you tried adding `fig.tight_layout()` before `fig.savefig`?

Comment: Did you try leaving out `bbox_inches='tight'` in the call to `fif.savefig()`?

Comment: @jared I've already tried that, it's still not working. You can test with my MWE above.

Comment: @JohanC I just tested, both `fig.savefig()` with or without `bbox_inches='tight'` have no effect, the z label still gets cut off.

Comment: Changing to `layout="tight"` (or equivalently, removing `layout="constrained"` and adding `fig.tight_layout()` before saving) and removing `bbox_inches="tight"` results in a figure with the z-label, although it has a bit of extra space on the sides (because of the figure size settings; changing it to `(7,6)` improves that).

Comment: @jared, thank you, I have tested your method, but compared to adding `ax.set_box_aspect(None, zoom=0.9)` in my MWE, your method adds even more spaces.